# How to replace multiple spaces by one tab

Tags: linux, bash, text-manipulation

I have some text files which contain some columns separated by a various number of spaces, but instead I need one single tab as a separator. Is it possible to do in Bash?

Comment: Thanks for the great input, but i have some single spaces inside a column, so i have to avoid tabbing a single space. sorry for that ,isinformation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To convert sequences of **more than one space** to a tab, but **leave individual spaces alone**:

```
sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' inputfile > outputfile
```

To do this for a number of files:

```
for inputfile in *
do
    sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' "$inputfile" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$inputfile"
done
```

or

```
for inputfile in *
do
    sed -i.bak 's/ \+ /\t/g' "$inputfile"
done
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/ \+ /\t/g' {} \;
```

Use this form for MacOS (or simply to avoid escaping the `+` in Linux):

```
sed -E 's/ + /\t/g'
```

along with other options, etc., that you need from the examples above.

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: \`.'`

Comment: @AaronFranke: What command did you try? None of the examples in my answer should produce that error.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. The `find` one on the bottom.

Comment: @AaronFranke: GNU `sed` doesn't like to have a space before the backup extension. I've edited my answer. Thanks for the report.

Comment: this is not a good solution for some, because single column that just-so-happens to be separated by one space will not get converted to \t

Comment: @MatthaeusGaiusCaesar: That may be true for *some*, but the OP specified not to touch single spaces and my answer clearly states this condition. To convert *all* spaces to tabs I think it's as simple as removing the space after the plus sign in my commands.

Answer (score 10):

If your character is multiple tabs you can also use `tr -s`:

```
-s, --squeeze-repeats   replace each input sequence of a repeated character
                        that is listed in SET1 with a single occurrence
```

For example:

```
my_file.txt | tr -s " "
```

All white spaces will become one.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed` to replace a number of spaces with a tab.:

Example to replace one-or-more-spaces with one tab:

```
cat spaced-file | sed 's/ \+/\t/g' > tabbed-file
```

Comment: The OP said the number of spaces was *variable*, so I don't think this solution will work.

Comment: @Mikel. Oops. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edit the post to allow matching for variable spaces.

Comment: Most useful answer here.

Comment: N.b. `sed $'s/  */\t/'` should work fine even on BSD (macOS) variants.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer using only `bash` is:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 ...; do
    echo -e "$col1\t$col2\t$col3..."
done <file
```

If there are a variable number of columns, you can do this, but it will only work in `bash`, not `sh`:

```
while read -r -a cols; do
    (
        IFS=$'\t'
        echo "${cols[*]}"
    )
done <file
```

e.g.

```
while read -r -a cols; do
    (
        IFS=$'\t'
        echo "${cols[*]}"
    )
done <<EOF
a b   c
d   e    f
  g h i
EOF
```

produces:

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
```

(there is a tab in between each, but it's hard to see when I paste it here)

You could also do it using `sed` or `tr`, but notice that the handling of blanks at the start produces different results.

sed:

```
$ sed 's/  */\t/g' << EOF
a b   c
d   e    f
  g h i
EOF
a       b       c
d       e       f
        g       h       i
```

tr:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\t' <<EOF
a b   c
d   e    f
  g h i
EOF
a       b       c
d       e       f
        g       h       i
```

Answer (score 2):

`perl -p -i -e 's/\s+/\t/g' *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SED script:

```
 sed 's/  */<TAB>/g' <spaces-file > tabs-file
```

Where <TAB> is pressing the TAB key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution:

```
    sed -E 's/\s+/\t/g' your_file > new_file
```

sed basically works in this manner (sed 's/old_pattern/new_pattern/g').
In this case the old pattern is "\s+" which means find space "s" one or more time "+" and the back slash "\" to interpret that as regular expression.
The new pattern is tab "\t" which is written in regular expression format and the "g" is apply the replacement to all lines "globally".

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser. You should take the time to explain your solution. For someone not familiar with *nix systems, sed and regular expressions, this looks like a pile of weird characters.